# How can I get mutiple passwords on one Wi-Fi network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

How can I get multiple passwords on one Wi-Fi network? I have three children and want each to have their separate password for cutoff and accountability.

Comment: Use guest/virtual networks if your AP supports it. Install custom firmware or buy a different AP if your current one does not. That's assuming your children won't share passwords. Otherwise, use MAC filtering, which is trivially bypassed by a determined attacker but perhaps not your children (age? tech-iness?).

Comment: SSID keys (passwords) are baked into the specifications, so they can't support extensions such as access control mechanisms, without additional software and whatnot (and you have to be on the network before you can interact with software on it). A Captive Portal would probably allow you the features you need, but that usually requires enterprise grade equipment.

Answer (score 2):

The way your question is worded implies a complex setup - something like using Radius on the WIFI connection - this implies something like Enterprise WPA encryption + A Radius setup.   There are, however easier ways of achieving your goals.

I'd start off by getting a router which supports DD-WRT (if yours doesn't already) and flash this firmware onto it.  This opens up a world of possibilities for you, including setting up a captive portal, offering multiple guest networks (different network for each guest ?), and using a proxy which can control what sites can be visited, and even time-of-day restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

If the children have each their own device, it might be easier to do it per device. Your modem/router may already have the necessary functionality (mine has).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I do this at work, but it's not overly hard or expensive to set up at home, though it can be a bit daunting to start with.

I use pfSense for my router, among the packages for that is freeRADIUS, but you can set up a freeRADIUS server (or other RADIUS server) any way you like and have WPA Enterprise security, which can be set with a username/password per user. Of course, your access points need to support WPA enterprise, but that's not a difficult bar to meet if you step away from home RouterAPSwitch-all-in-one-box products.

The RADIUS server needs to be set up with the users and their passwords, and the AP's (typically by address) and their passwords for accessing the server to authenticate users. The APs need to be set up with their access passwords on their side (they don't need to know about the users, that's the server's job) and knowing what address the server is at.

A simpler approach for your specific case is to get APs that support at least 4 SSIDs, assigning one to each child and one to the parents, but that does have performance impacts, and does not scale well.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual AP is a function that allows you to create multiple SSIDs and use different passwords, but unfortunately not all routers have this function.